# Java_java_net_PlainSocketImpl_socketSetOption

Tags: sockets, java-native-interface, java-8, java

in open-jdk-8 :

this jin function : Java_java_net_PlainSocketImpl_socketSetOption:

```
/*                                                                                                                                                                                            
     * SO_TIMEOUT is a no-op on Solaris/Linux                                                                                                                                                     
     */
    if (cmd == java_net_SocketOptions_SO_TIMEOUT) {
        return;
    }
```

file: openjdk7/jdk/src/solaris/native/java/net/PlainSocketImpl.c

does this mean , on linux setOption of SO_TIMEOUT will be ignored ?

I am can't found the jin for linux. but the solaris's code seems also works for linux .

Comment: That's what the code appears to do? Do you have a reason to suspect this is not the case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it just means it isn't implemented as a socket option. Some platforms don't support it. On those platforms `select()` or friends are used.

Answer (score 0):

The source inside solaris folder is also used for Linux.

`SO_TIMEOUT` is ignored in `Java_java_net_PlainSocketImpl_socketSetOption0`. But `timeout` is kept as a field when `AbstractPlainSocketImpl.setOption` is called:

```
case SO_TIMEOUT:
    if (val == null || (!(val instanceof Integer)))
            throw new SocketException("Bad parameter for SO_TIMEOUT");
    int tmp = ((Integer) val).intValue();
    if (tmp < 0)
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("timeout < 0");
// Saved for later use
    timeout = tmp;
    break;
```

And `timeout` is used when doing read in `SocketInputStream`:

```
public int read(byte b[], int off, int length) throws IOException {
    return read(b, off, length, impl.getTimeout());
}
```